# Add text to a custom Back Button iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a backbutton with an image I'm using in my navigation controller, and I'd like to set the text over top of the image. I tried this but it doesn't seem to show up:

```
    UIImage *normalBackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_tl.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; backButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalBackImage.size.width, normalBackImage.size.height );
    [backButton setImage:normalBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.titleLabel.text = @"Back";
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. set the title's color, else you'll not see anything :)

   - setTitleColor:forState:

2.
dont try to set the image (which means FOREGROUND image). Instead set the BACKGROUND image :)

```
– setBackgroundImage:forState:
```

sample:

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50);
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"Bla" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *normalBackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_tl.png"];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:normalBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:backButton];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Doing that doesn't seem to show the label though.


        backButton.titleLabel.text = @"Back";
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:normalBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UILabel and add it as a subview to your UIImage. That would look something like this (writing code outside the compiler, might not be perfect)

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setText:@"My Label Text"];
[image addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: I think I like the answer above mine more :)